# Heroku isn't updating my CSS and JS

Tags: css, ruby, heroku, sinatra

First thing I should mention is that I'm NOT using Rails. I don't have a `rake assets:precompile` task (tried it anyway, didn't work). I don't have a `public/assets` folder either (tried `git rm -r public/assets` anyway, also didn't work).

For a long time, I was using Dropbox to deploy to Heroku (I'm quite the newbie to code) - I was planning on moving to git in about a month or so. But given this issue, I made the move today and tried pushing through git - also didn't work. i.e. I did a `git pull`, settled all the conflicts and then did `git push`. Still nothing.

Basically, Heroku isn't loading any of my new CSS and JS. It detects the files just fine. Running `git push` now says everything is up-to-date, running `git status` says there is nothing to commit. But using Chrome's inspect tool, the JS and CSS files don't have the new code I wrote.

I also tried adding the gem `rack-flash-session` to my Gemfile and requiring `'rack/flash/test'` in my application_controller - this actually crashed the whole app and I removed it.

I also tried installing the `heroku-repo` plugin and running `heroku repo:purge_cache --app my-app-name` but that also didn't work

Running the code locally, everything works fine. It's just the online version that's failing.

I updated the Heroku CLI just before trying any of this and (you guessed it!), also didn't work.

I don't know what other info you'd need, so let me know in the comments and I'll be happy to provide them :)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show a `tree` of your repo, and also try control shift r in the browser to reset the cache?

Comment: Oh god! That was all it took. `Ctrl+Shift+r`. And after all the time spent on more complicated things. Lol. Thanks a lot @maxpleaner ! If you put that as an answer I can mark this question done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh the page with control + shift + r. This will clear the client-side assets cache and get the newly updated ones. You could also look for a gem that does cache-busting "asset fingerprinting" - this is a unique string that's appended to the asset files which prevents browsers from using a stale copy. I searched a little but I can't definitively point you to something that works with sinatra. Maybe you'll be able to find a gem that works though.

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner ! I'll be sure to look into that gem!

Comment: Wow, how could I have not done this. Thanks!!